# what return mysqli_insert_id()?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i want to get last id from table
i found

```
mysqli_insert_id()
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp

function that return last `id`
but i want to know that it is **just last record of table** or **id of this inserting**?
because i want id of this inserting that when several people inserting in db every body get her *own last id*

thank you so...

Comment: It returns the id of last insert. Hence the name, `insert_id`. So yes, it will be different for everyone.

Comment: it autoincrement fields about only, isn't it?

Comment: @Aristona so you said that can i use this for my site?

Comment: @vp_arth yes it's only for auto-increment fields

Comment: [**Poh-tay-toe**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_insert_id.asp) - [**Poh-tah-toe**](http://php.net/mysqli_insert_id)

Comment: Look: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

The link you are using is wrong. Here is a proper one:

http://php.net/mysqli_insert_id

And so it says

> The mysqli_insert_id() function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute. If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.

Comment: just call this function right after running insert query